# Can a curve be defined by the function of the angle between the tangent line and an axis?

Tags: geometry, derivatives, curves

The answer to this question is something I *should* know...but without regular practice working mathematics the answer is falling into some shadow of my understanding.

I have a curve which lies entirely within a Cartesian plane. The horizontal and vertical axes are represented by X and Y, respectively. The only thing I know about the curve is that the angle $(\lambda)$ this curve makes with the X-axis at any given value of Y is defined by this function:
$$\lambda=f(y)=\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{y})$$

I need to determine a function which will yield values of X with respect to Y according to this curve.

[Generic Curve Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDxOx.png)

---

What I tried to do, and what I am unsure of, was to assume that the function which describes $\lambda$ is equivalent to derivative of the curve. Which would mean the equation of the curve could be found by:
$$x=\int f(y)\ dy=\int \tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{y})=y\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{y})+\frac{1}{2}a\ln(a^2+y^2)$$

Is this correct? Can the curve be entirely defined by the function of the tangent angle with respect to y?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: aka a gradient or first derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The function that describes $\lambda$ is closely related to the derivative of the curve - the derivative is simply the gradient of the tangent so $\lambda$ is simply $\tan^{-1} (\frac{dy}{dx})$. So your assumption that the angle is the derivative is not quite correct.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that makes sense now. I knew there was something a little off about describing a derivative as an angle. I still am unsure how to get the equation of the curve so that I could plug in Y values and determine X values.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't be integrating the angle with respect to $y$.

We have
$$\tan\lambda=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
so
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{a}{y}.
$$

Comment: First, thank you. I am having troubling filling in the blanks to get from $$\lambda '=\frac{a}{y}$$ to the actual equation of the curve. Especially since it was incorrect to integrate with respect to $y$. Could you elaborate on the procedure?

Comment: why is $\lambda'=a/y$?  What you were given is $\lambda=\tan^{-1}(a/y)$.

Comment: Sorry! You're right, I meant to say: if the derivative of the curve is $\frac{a} {y} $ then how would I get the equation of the curve? My first thought was to perform $$\int\frac{a} {y} dy$$ yielding $$a \ln (y) $$ But because of the first answer given by user10354138 I am unsure if this is correct.

Comment: No!  Separating variables in $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{a}y$ gives $\int y\,\mathrm{d}y=\int a\,\mathrm{d}x$.